how to make the react index.html international
I want to do a international with the react index.html title, now I am tried like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title id="title">TeXHub-走进TeX的世界</title>
    <link href="/css/viewer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fontawesome-free-6.5.1-web/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
    <script>
    const lang = navigator.language || 'en';
    const translations = {
      en: {
        title: "TeXHub - Enter the World of TeX",
      },
      zh: {
        title: "TeXHub-走进TeX的世界",
      },
      fr: {
        title: "TeXHub - Entrez dans le Monde de TeX",
      }
    };
    const { title } = translations[lang] || translations.en;
    document.getElementById('title').textContent = title;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

this works with current language but I still want the index.html will switch when I changed the language in the web UI. In the function component I will use the:
const { i18n } = useTranslation();
i18n.changeLanguage(name);

this will make the component changed the language but not work with the static index.html, how to switch the language in the index.html?
